# Como usar 2 funciones en un solo boton?

Tags: php

Hola amigos el dia de hoy tengo un problema y es que no se como hacer para realizar 2 funciones al mismo tiempo en un script, tengo el siguiente codigo que ya he buscado en internet como hacer pero no me funciona la segunda funcion solo la primera y me gustaria saber que es lo que estoy haciendo mal, este es el codigo:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return go_submit(1);return confirm('Are you sure you want go?')">Go Now!';
```

por favor queridos amigos necesito saber como hacer que los 2 return funcionen, el primero es este:

```
return go_submit(1)
```

y la segunda funcion es esta:

```
return confirm('Are you sure you want go?')
```

solo me funciona la primera, pero despues de darle click no me aparece el mensaje de confirmacion, necesito que me aparezca el mensaje de confirmacion porque asi evito clicking o presionar rapidamente el boton de Go Now! osea poner una pausa  por parte de los usuarios!

Si alguien esta dispuesto a ayudar le agradeceria infinitamente, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`confirm()` abre un cuadro de diálogo, y en función de la respuesta del usuario devuelve `true` o `false`. Supongo aunque no lo dices que quieres ejecutar `go_submit()` si el usuario confirma, así que sólo tienes que llamar a `go_submit()` si `confirm()` devuelve true:

```
<a href="#" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want go?')) return go_submit(1); return false">Go Now!</a>
```

Comment: Hola querido amigo muchas gracias por tu ayuda, en este momento pruebo a ver que tal me va saludos! y feliz dia! =)

Comment: Muchas gracias querido amigo, eso era exactamente lo que necesitaba, le pido a Dios que te bendiga y te multiplique en abundancia, muchas gracias, espero que estes muy bien y saludos de parte de jose! =) Feliz dia!

Answer (score 0):

Quita el return ese interrumpe la cadena por eso nunca llegas a la segunda funcion, aunque me parece que tu idea esta un tanto herrada

Seguro que quieres ejecutar ambas funciones? no sera que quieres pedir una confirmacion del usuario y en caso de ser positiva entonces hacer el envio?

Si es el caso debes hacer modificar la funcion del envio

```
<a href="#" onclick="go_submit()">Go Now!'; 


function go_submit(){
    var confirmUser = confirm("xxxxxxxx");
  if(!confirmUser) return;
  
  //... todo tu codigo de envio o lo que tengas que hacedr
}
```

Comment: Hola querido amigo pruebo en este momento y te digo como me fue, muchas gracias, realmente que la ignorancia es el peor de los enemigo por eso quiero aprender bien php saludos y feliz dia! =)